# Hide application window NW.js and Electron

Tags: javascript, hide, electron, desktop-application, nw.js

I am using `NW.js` and Electron to build desktop application from our current Web Application.

I need to launch the application in hidden mode, it should only show some error alert message or confirmation alert message when required.

How to I hide the application window i.e. my desktop application window using `NW.js` and/or Electron.

I have no clue as of now as I am just starting with `NW.js` and Electron.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

**NW.js only solution:**

First, add into package.json:

```
"window": {
    "show": false
}
```

Second, use some code for notifications, like:

```
<script>
    const options = {
        body: 'Hello there, user3873552'
    };

    new Notification('Stackoverflow', options);
</script>
```

Alternatively, feel free to find a cross-platform npm-library for notifications and confirmations.